# Declaring and Assigning an Array with Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to declare and assign an array while using generics and I'm having a little bit of trouble with this. I noticed that it was impossible to assign an array normally using generics. I found this work around, but it doesn't seem to work for me. It outputs a NullPointerException once it gets to the Array.newInstance(c,capacity). I'm just expecting this code to declare the array. Any ideas why this won't function the way it's expected to?

```
public class MyHeap<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Heap<T> {
Class<T> type;
T[] heap;
int size;
int capacity;


MyHeap(int x){
    capacity = x;
    size = 0;
    arraySet(type, capacity);
}

private void arraySet(Class<T> c, int capacity){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final T[] heap = (T[]) Array.newInstance(c, capacity);
    this.heap = heap;
}
```

}

Comment: Because `type` is `null`. You could use a `List`, then you don't need a reference to the component type.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that. But how do I set that to anything. Unfortunately I has to be an array. I am doing this as part of a lab for my data structures and algorithms class and it requires this implementation to use an array

Comment: Why not just use a `Comparable<T>[]`? You already know it's component type: `Comparable`.

Comment: For information on creating generic arrays, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java?rq=1

Comment: I used that link to get this far...but I don't understand what Class<E> is? How do I set a value to that?

Comment: I've reopened this question and answered your fundamental issue from your comment, but I suggest editing your post to shift the focus to your real question, rather than asking about the NPE.

Comment: I'd suggest use a `Comparable<T>[]` like @John suggests, or even piggyback on `ArrayList<T>` to implement a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your root problem:

> ...but I don't understand what Class is? How do I set a value to that?

Your options are:

1. Pass it as a parameter to your constructor:

   ```
   MyHeap (int x, Class<T> type) { this.type = type; ... }

   // Usage
   new MyHeap(64, Integer.class);
   ```
2. Pass something of that type to the constructor (not appropriate for your case) and use its type information:

   ```
   MyHeap (int x, T obj) { this.type = obj.getClass(); ... }

   // Usage
   new MyHeap(64, new Integer());
   ```

   [`List#toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) uses this pattern for this purpose.
3. Just store an `Object` array internally (`Object[] heap`), then you don't have to have the type available when you create the array. [`ArrayList` is implemented this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList), and as long as you use `T` in your function parameter lists, the compiler will verify that everything is cool. For `T` return types you'll have to cast the objects to a `T` before returning them ([example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.elementData%28int%29)) but as long as you have the invariant that every one of those `Object`s is a `T`, then it will always be a safe cast.

I'd go with option 3 as it leads to the simplest API.